# How to grep the two different pattern statements from the same file seperately

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a log file which has two different type of statements.

One statement is like

```
LOG:Update For User 12932030 statement  @2113 set startduration='2017-01-03 00:01:30'...
LOG:Update For User 12932030 statement @2033 set startduration=endduration ...
LOG:Update For User 12932031 statement @2403 set startduration='2017-01-04 00:02:30'...
LOG:Update For User 12932032 statement  @3113 set startduration='2017-01-09 00:03:30'...
LOG:Update For User 12932033 statement @9313 set startduration=endduration ...
LOG:Update For User 12932034 statement @9126 set startduration=endduration ...
```

So from this I want to extract both seperately.But my current approach is like

```
grep -i " LOG:Update For User set startduration"  log.csv > result.csv
```

which does not differentiate between both.I am not sure how can I incorporate the pattern after startduration .Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a more examples of logs content and two types desired outputs?

Comment: @EgorVasilyev Is the above fine?it's basically one deals with the server time while other resets the star time to endtime

Comment: @Ricky, *which does not differentiate between both* - cause you're trying to match the same pattern on all lines, that's obvious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `grep` twice:

Desired output type №1:

```
 grep -E "LOG:Update For User [0-9]* statement *@[0-9]* set startduration='" log.csv

LOG:Update For User 12932030 statement  @2113 set startduration='2017-01-03 00:01:30'...
LOG:Update For User 12932031 statement @2403 set startduration='2017-01-04 00:02:30'...
LOG:Update For User 12932032 statement  @3113 set startduration='2017-01-09 00:03:30'...
```

Desired output type №2:

```
grep -E "LOG:Update For User [0-9]* statement *@[0-9]* set startduration=[^']" log.csv

LOG:Update For User 12932030 statement @2033 set startduration=endduration ...
LOG:Update For User 12932033 statement @9313 set startduration=endduration ...
LOG:Update For User 12932034 statement  @9126 set startduration=endduration ...
```

Comment: I am so sorry I forgot to mention that in the LOGS after User there is `@numeric` which is different for each line

Comment: @Ricky, i corrected my answer. See above

Comment: Sorry again missed one more thing in Logs.So sorry for the inconvineience.But i tried `grep -E "LOG:Update For User [0-9]* statement @[0-9]* set startduration='" log.csv but printed empty file
`

Comment: Oh i see i think i missed an asterix before @

Comment: @Ricky, i corrected my answer again. Your output is empty because input data has several spaces after `statement`

Comment: @Ricky, are your example contain all kinds of lines from real log files? Does each line start from pattern `LOG:Update For User [0-9]* statement *@[0-9]* set startduration`?